# How to set/get socket RTT in linux socket programming?

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

I need to set or get RTT in socket(`AF_INET`, `SOCK_RAW`, `IPPROTO_TCP`) way.

What do I need to do next to control such RTT in socket programming? In other words, how to find such RTT parameter?

Comment: There's no function for that in the API. Just send a message to the other end, have the other end send it back, and time it. Not so hard.

Comment: Will [tcp-timestamp](http://ithitman.blogspot.in/2013/02/tcp-timestamp-demystified.html) option help?

Comment: It isn't set, it's measured, by TCP.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux you can get the RTT by calling `getsockopt()` with `TCP_INFO`:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>

/* ... */

tcp_info info;
socklen_t tcp_info_length = sizeof info;
ret = getsockopt(sock, SOL_TCP, TCP_INFO, &info, &tcp_info_length);
printf("rtt: %u microseconds\n", info.tcpi_rtt);
```

Comment: Can I get the rtt time of accepted socket like this

Comment: @user786 Yes, that is the RTT as calculated by the TCP stack.

Comment: so where I call `getsockopt()`  is it after the call to `accept()` or after the call to `read(..)`

Comment: @user786 It will work in both places, but the value will change as the socket is used, because it is an estimation calculated as new packets are sent and confirmed through that connection. I am not sure `read()` will have any effect on the value.

Answer (score 1):

To measure the Round Trip Time (RTT) write a simple client-server application where one node:

1. Reads the current time with `clock_gettime()`
2. Sends a message to the other node using `write()` on the (already opened) socket
3. Waits the message back using `read()`
4. Reads the current time using `clock_gettime()`

RTT is the difference between the two times.

Comment: POSIX.1-2008 marks `gettimeofday(2)` as obsolescent. `clock_gettime(2)` should be used instead (or `time(2)`).

Comment: Right. Fixed. Thank you.