# Extract TCP round trip time (RTT) estimations on linux

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, linux-kernel, cubic

I have apache server running on Ubuntu. Client connects and downloads an image. I need to extract RTT estimations for the underlying TCP connection. Is there a way to do this? Maybe something like running my tcp stack in debug mode to have it log this info somewhere?

Note that I don't want to run tcpdump and extract RTTs from the recorded trace! I need the TCP stack's RTT estimations (apparently this is part of the info you can get with TCP_INFO socket option). Basically need something like tcpprob (kprobe) to insert a hook and record the estimated RTT of the TCP connection on every incoming packet (or on every change).

**UPDATE**:

I found a solution. rtt, congestion window and more can be logged using tcpprobe. I posted an answer below.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231600/fetching-the-tcp-rtt-in-linux

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I'm familiar with "ss", but it's not exactly what I need as it will give me a very coarse sampling of the RTT. I need something like tcpprob (kprobe) to insert a hook and record the estimated RTT of the TCP connection on every incoming packet (or on every change).

Comment: Hmm.  Well Linux congestion control algorithms are pluggable modules in the `net/ipv4/` directory.  Each computes rtt differently (and [reno](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_cong.c) doesn't compute it at all!), so I'm thinking you'll have to hook into a particular implementation.  I see you tagged cubic, so that's [tcp_cubic.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_cubic.c).  I don't think there's a generic method of getting the rtt, but I could certainly be wrong...

Comment: Thanks @indiv ! Yeah I haven't yet been able to find a generic way to do it, I probably need to get my hands dirty and do it myself. I am also experimenting with ss and see if it actually suffice for what I need. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Oh boy! I can't believe tcpprobe was doing this for me the whole time and I missed it! haha I will post an answer in a bit

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48370480/43046 ?

Comment: Interesting. No I have not, but will look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using [***tcpprobe***](http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/tcpprobe), which is a module that inserts a hook into the tcp_recv processing path using *kprobe* records the state of a TCP connection in response to incoming packets.

Let's say you want to probe tcp connection on port 443, you need to do the following:

```
sudo modprobe tcp_probe port=443 full=1
sudo chmod 444 /proc/net/tcpprobe
cat /proc/net/tcpprobe > /tmp/output.out &
pid=$!
```

**full=1**: log on every ack packet received

**full=0**: log on only condo changes (if you use this your output might be empty)

Now *pid* is the process which is logging the probe. To stop, simply kill this process:

```
kill $pid
```

The format of output.out (according to the [source](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/ipv4/tcp_probe.c) at line 198):

```
[time][src][dst][length][snd_nxt][snd_una][snd_cwnd][ssthresh][snd_wnd][srtt][rcv_wnd]
```

Comment: The RTT is in "ms"

Comment: It doesn't seem to be available since at least 5.1.x. Do you know if it was removed or just renamed ?

Comment: Hmm...unfortunately I don't know, as I haven't work with this for a while now.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done without the need for any additional kernel modules using the [`ss`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ss.8.html) command (part of the [`iproute`](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/iproute2) package), which can provide detailed info on open sockets. It won't show it for every packet but most of this info is calculated over a number of packets. E.g. To list the currently open TCP (`t` option) sockets and associated internal TCP info (`i`) information - including congestion control algorithm, `rtt`, `cwnd` etc:

```
ss -ti
```

Here's some example output:

```
State       Recv-Q Send-Q        Local Address:Port        Peer Address:Port
ESTAB       0      0             192.168.56.102:ssh        192.168.56.1:46327
  cubic wscale:6,7 rto:201 rtt:0.242/0.055 ato:40 mss:1448 rcvmss:1392
advmss:1448 cwnd:10 bytes_acked:33169 bytes_received:6069 segs_out:134
segs_in:214 send 478.7Mbps lastsnd:5 lastrcv:6 lastack:5 
pacing_rate 955.4Mbps rcv_rtt:3 rcv_space:28960
```

Comment: ss documentation does not have any of those fields. E.g. what does "rtt: x/y" even mean?

Comment: For details on the fields take a look at the man page for `ss` linked to in the answer (Some distribution man pages seem to lack this info). For full details see the src code: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/tree/misc/ss.c#n2468